# Generating insert statement dynamically based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two separate deployment of Student Table.  In one case student table contains department Id and in other case it doesn't contain department Id.

I have a common post deployment script for both cases to insert value in student table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Student
(
    DeptId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    StudentName VARCHAR(20)
)
GO

DECLARE @DeptId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

IF COL_LENGTH('dbo.Department', 'DeptId') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    SELECT @DeptId = DeptId
    FROM dbo.Department
    WHERE DeptName = 'Computer'
END

INSERT INTO dbo.Student(DeptId, StudentName)
SELECT @DeptId, 'TBAG'
```

But When I don't have department Id column this script doesn't work

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
>     Invalid column name 'DeptId'.

Comment: If you want to run the same queries on the same tables, fix the tables so they have the same columns.

Comment: To some client I don't want to give dept Id feature while other can have that feature. How can I keep this script same for both cases. I mean I am open to change query into string and run it under EXEC. But I am having hard time converting this into string.

Comment: . . You should probably control such features using parameters at a higher level.  The data structures should be the same, or you will face a maintenance nightmare.  So, you code can be filled with `if` statements checking if the feature is enabled.

Comment: @GordonLinoff At code level we are using castle installation. So based on name two separate installation we are handling. There are not much if statements required. Database level I have just one of this kind script. For that I cannot go and write two separate scripts for database installation. I am just trying to Execute script as string and put one condition based on department Id column exists

Comment: but how your insert statement work if column doesn't exist. your insert statement inside if condition right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Student
  (
     DeptId      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
     StudentName VARCHAR(20)
  )

GO

IF Col_length('dbo.Department', 'DeptId') IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO dbo.Student
                  (DeptId,
                   StudentName)
      SELECT DeptId,
             'TBAG'
      FROM   dbo.Department
      WHERE  DeptName = 'Computer'
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO dbo.Student
                  (StudentName)
      SELECT 'TBAG'
  END
```